# How to add column with fixed value to imported data Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to merge data from two spreadsheets and add column with the file ID on each row.

---

Spreadsheet 1 Columns => A B C D

Spreadsheet 2 Columns => O P Q R

Spreadsheet merged Columns => 'X' A B C D O P Q R

edited: <s>where column X contains ID of spreadsheet.</s>

...where 'X' is not column from Spreadsheet 1 or Spreadsheet 2 but it is new column in merged new spreadsheet and contains text/ID of spreadsheet where is origin of the row.

---

I use now this code...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet1-ID"; "'Sheet'!A:D");"SELECT * WHERE Col1!=''");
  QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet2-ID"; "'Sheet'!O:R");"SELECT * WHERE Col1!=''")
})
```

...and I get:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
O1 P1 Q1 R1
O2 P2 Q2 R2
```

But I need:

```
spreadsheet1-ID A1 B1 C1 D1
spreadsheet1-ID A2 B2 C2 D2
spreadsheet2-ID O1 P1 Q1 R1
spreadsheet2-ID O2 P2 Q2 R2
```

Can I use something like this to add fixed column with ID in QUERY?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet1-ID"; "'Sheet'!A:D");"SELECT 'ID1', * WHERE Col1!=''");
  QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet2-ID"; "'Sheet'!O:R");"SELECT 'ID1', * WHERE Col1!=''")
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`={QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet1-ID", "'Sheet'!A:X"),"SELECT Col24,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1!=''");QUERY(importrange("spreadsheet2-ID", "'Sheet'!O:X"),"SELECT Col10,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1!=''")}`

To add an ID that does not exist in the sheets themselves, try this formula:

`=ArrayFormula({IF(SIGN(row(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(QUERY(importrange("key1", "'Sheet'!A:D"),"WHERE Col1!=''"))))),"ID1",),QUERY(importrange("key1", "'Sheet'!A:D"),"WHERE Col1!=''");IF(SIGN(row(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(QUERY(importrange("key2", "'Sheet'!O:R"),"WHERE Col1!=''"))))),"ID2",),QUERY(importrange("key2", "'Sheet'!O:R"),"WHERE Col1!=''")})`

You can see it working in this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sSHP0sekUc5PxnubpnieWthD2H_9s4P2JWqmtxM906o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry my fault. I didn't write it clearly.

The 'X' is not column from Spreadsheet 1 or Spreadsheet 2 but it is new column in merged new spreadsheet and contains text/ID of spreadsheet where is origin of the row.

Comment: oh I see - I've posted an amended formula above.  You can change the 'ID1' and 'ID2' values as required.

Comment: Wow, this is just pure magic. The logic of your solution is fascinating! Works grate, thanks a lot.