# Google sheets multiple queries, how do I append the sheet name

Tags: google-sheets

```
=sort({QUERY(Kraft!A2:K500, "SELECT A,G,H WHERE G!='' AND J=''", 1); QUERY(Beacon!A2:H500, "SELECT A,B,F WHERE B!='' AND G=''", 1)},3,true)
```

Comes out like this

Pro Number 1    Trailer 1   Date 1

Pro Number 2    Trailer 2   Date 2

Pro Number 3    Trailer 3   Date 3

Pro Number 4    Trailer 4   Date 4

I would like to append the sheet name, or even simply text (sheet names shouldnt change much, so I can manually update the queries as needed)

Kraft   Pro Number 1    Trailer 1   Date 1

Beacon  Pro Number 2    Trailer 2   Date 2

Kraft   Pro Number 3    Trailer 3   Date 3

Beacon  Pro Number 4    Trailer 4   Date 4

Also I should note that there will be about 10 queries in total

Comment: I think I found the solution... will update

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157389/how-to-add-column-with-fixed-value-to-imported-data-google-spreadsheet

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422542/19529694) is straight forward, if you can include your example please do, to test it.

Comment: I failed horribly with this method and not sure why - going to test some answers below now but here was my attempt at modifying that code which gives me a array literal error

=ArrayFormula({IF(SIGN(row(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(QUERY(Kraft!A:J,"SELECT A,G,H WHERE G!='' AND J=''"))))),"KRAFT",),QUERY("'Kraft'!A:J","SELECT A,G,H WHERE G!='' AND J=''");IF(SIGN(row(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(QUERY("'Beacon'!A:J","SELECT A,B,F WHERE B!='' AND G=''"))))),"BEACON",),QUERY("'Beacon'!A:J","SELECT A,B,F WHERE B!='' AND G=''")})

Comment: To make it easier for respondents, please include your example, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
=SORT({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REPT(","&"Kraft",
                              COUNTA(QUERY(Kraft!A2:K500, "SELECT A,G,H WHERE G!='' AND J=''", 1))),"^.",""),",")),
 QUERY(Kraft!A2:K500, "SELECT A,G,H WHERE G!='' AND J=''", 1);
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REPT(","&"Beacon",
                              QUERY(Beacon!A2:H500, "SELECT A,B,F WHERE B!='' AND G=''", 1)),"^.",""),",")), 
 QUERY(Beacon!A2:H500, "SELECT A,B,F WHERE B!='' AND G=''", 1)},4,true)
```

[image]

Comment: function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size, expect: 12. Actual 6

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SORT({
 QUERY(Kraft!A2:K500,  
 "select 'Kraft', A,G,H where G is not null and J='' label'Kraft'''", 1); 
 QUERY(Beacon!A2:H500, 
 "select 'Beacon',A,B,F where B is not null and G='' label'Beacon'''", 1)}, 4, 1)
```

---

### update:

```
=SORT({
 IFERROR(QUERY(Kraft!A2:K500,  
 "select 'Kraft', A,G,H where G is not null and J='' label'Kraft'''",  1), {"","","",""}); 
 IFERROR(QUERY(Beacon!A2:H500, 
 "select 'Beacon',A,B,F where B is not null and G='' label'Beacon'''", 1), {"","","",""})}, 4, 1)
```

Comment: I totally overlooked `label`. thanks

Comment: I tried to research label but I could only find tutorials for changing column headers. Thank you so much

Comment: I have another question, it appears if a query produces no results, an Array Literal occurs. IFERROR on each query can fix that right? I can research myself if you could kindly point me in the right direction

Comment: @JamesBurton answer updated. see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471